# Programmatically find the region of an azure function

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio, azure-functions

I have a service that invokes the azure function API using the Managed Service Identity authentication token. I want to be able to invoke the correct regional azure function based on the region from code. So for example, if the region I pass is useast2, I need to invoke the azure function that resides in useast2 region programmatically using C#. How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: Could you explain a little bit more your use case ? Looks like you re trying to do global load balancing, Traffic manager or Front door will do the job for you.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. The use case I have is, my service needs to invoke the azure function API based on the region. So, say, I have a region useast2 in code, I need to invoke the corresponding useast2 azure function API. I know how to invoke an azure function as is, but this time I want to invoke the azure function that is present in that region.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this line of code for find the regions name. `REGION_NAME` regions name of the app.

```
Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("REGION_NAME")
```

In my case, I am create a webjob for find the region using below code.

```cs
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace CheckErrorOrLog
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Azure web job Start");
            for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i);
                Thread.Sleep(2 * 60 * 1000);
                Console.WriteLine(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("REGION_NAME"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output

[image]
You can find other environment variable on these [Microsoft Document App Environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/reference-app-settings?tabs=kudu,dotnet#app-environment)